# How do I capture keystrokes without stale state in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make an on screen keyboard in react that also accepts keystrokes from a real keyboard.

The virtual keyboard works as expected. However, once I added a switch to enable and disable both keyboards (real and virtual), the real one broke. Whenever any key is pressed on the real keyboard, it logs that it is disabled even though it is not.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App(props) {
  const [isKeyboardEnabled, setIsKeyboardEnabled] = useState(false);
  const [str, setStr] = useState("");

  const onClick = (v) => {
    if (isKeyboardEnabled) {
      setStr((str) => str + v);
    } else {
      console.log(`keyboard not enabled ("${v}")`);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>str: "{str}"</div>
      <br />
      <Keyboard onClick={onClick} />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setIsKeyboardEnabled((v) => !v)}>
        isKeyboardEnabled: {isKeyboardEnabled.toString()}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Keyboard(props) {
  const handleKeyDown = (v) => {
    if (!/^[a-z]$/.test(v)) return;
    props.onClick(v);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const fn = (e) => handleKeyDown(e.key);
    document.addEventListener("keydown", fn);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", fn);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {[..."abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"].map((v, i) => (
        <button key={i} onClick={() => handleKeyDown(v)}>{v}</button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Why is this behavior occurring, and how do I fix this?

Comment: [Try this](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/distracted-wescoff-vt7c7k?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js) It was due to you not adding `isKeyboardEnabled` to dependency array of `useEffect`.

Comment: I think `isKeyboardEnabled` state is only for the physical keyboard, not both virtual and physical keyboards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be a potential closure issue in the `onClick` function and it may be maintaining only the initial state of `isKeyboardEnabled` state which is false and therefore always executes the else case.

Please try the following.

Update the `onClick`:

```
      const onClick = useCallback(
    (v) => {
      if (isKeyboardEnabled) {
        setStr((str) => str + v);
      } else {
        console.log(`keyboard not enabled ("${v}")`);
      }
    },
    [isKeyboardEnabled]
  );
```

update the `handleKeyDown` and `useEffect` of `Keyboard` as follows:

```
    const handleKeyDown = useCallback(
    (v) => {
      if (props.isKeyboardEnabled && /^[a-z]$/.test(v)) {
        props.onClick(v);
      }
    },
    [props.isKeyboardEnabled, props.onClick]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const fn = (e) => handleKeyDown(e.key);
    document.addEventListener("keydown", fn);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", fn);
    };
  }, [handleKeyDown]);
```